# Why does Excel Match function yield incorrect result?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am experimenting with the Match function in Excel. As seen in the photo, I tried to find the number 27.04 with the Match function. However, even though the number clearly exists, the function returns #NA. This problem usually appears when I use Match on cells that contain function. Can anyone explain what is going on? Thank you

Attached photo:
[image: attached photo]

Comment: Do you have the same issue while looking for a value in columns C and D?

Comment: If you increase the decimal places in the floor area is it exactly 27.04?  The 0 on the end of the Match function tells it to look for an exact match.

Comment: Scratch that last comment - it is exactly 27.04.  Also returns #N/A for 6.44 and 7.8.  Interesting.... not sure why though.

Comment: It does seem to be a rounding problem.  Update column E to `=ROUND(C5*D5,2)` and your MATCH formula will work.  Found this:  Differences between =A1=B1 and MATCH(B1,A1,0) usually reflect infinitesimal differences in the binary representation of calculated values. For the same reason, you might also find that =A1-B1=0 is FALSE, even though =A1=B1 is TRUE. [Excel match returning #N/A despite matches existing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-match-returning-na-despite-matches-existing/0bfa20cf-c641-432e-a873-43f50cdd2e15)

Comment: Numbers are stored internally in a different format than shown in display. As as @DarrenBartrup-Cook states, use a formula that allows for a small difference between the reference and the value in the cell, e.g., if ABS(val - ref) < 0.001, consider it a match.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked

Comment: Do the Floor area column have the formula?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Excel. Matching floating-point numbers has long been a problem for Excel, due to how numbers are stored in memory. A couple of options at this point:

1. Rather than hard-coding the value you're looking for into the formula, use a cell reference. For example, put 27.04 in cell G6 and use the formula `=MATCH(G6,$E$5:$E$13,0)`. This is the option I would personally recommend.
2. Round the calculations in column E. Using the ROUND function to round your results to two decimal places will allow for an exact match. So, `=ROUND($C5*$D5,2)`. This allows you to use the hard-coded value in the formula if you really need to.

Comment: The rounding method worked! I guess there are far more decimals than displayed. Thank you

Comment: It's related to how numbers are stored and processed in binary, as @Jeorje described. In the base 10 number system, there are no more decimals; in binary, there are. Since Excel needs to do its calculations in binary but display the results in decimal, we get occasional glitches like this one. There's a technical discussion of it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Answer (score 1):

This was all kinds of fascinating but it turns out the variance in value is in the 15th decimal place... and the integer part being two digits means that what Excel will ever display, even in the number formatting box/functionality exactly 13 decimal places.

Those are all zeros so we see the "27.0400000000000" when the value actually is `3.5527136788005E-15` higher than a true "27.04":  27.0400000000000**035527136788005**.

Excel has always used far more digits than it returns to the cell value. Said to be 27-28 digits depending on sign, but always did truly truncate the values for placing in-cell as results.

It is clearly now providing all the accuracy, at least in version 2209. Count the above out and it is 28 significant figures. I only got that using `F9` in cell on the following formula:

```
=MATCH( (C1-C4), $C$1:$C$10, 0)
```

which does use the `(C1-C4)` properly (after I thought about changing `MATCH`'s last parameter) but WILL compute using `F9` to give the remainder above regardless of how the matching turns out.

I will say I never did that before, so I don't know if it is new or if we could have retrieved all that extra accuracy for decades... Holy #$%*& if we always could have.

However, while I wondered about Excel taking a new tack on displaying non-perfect binary-decimal results, thinking such was happening (really something like 27.0400000000002, but Excel realizing the problem (finally) and displaying it "perfectly" regardless. And it being maybe early days and not fully adapted to all functions, and the usual so on. But being hugely interesting if so. NOT that though, just... an amazing provision of the full value Excel was using internally.

**Which is bigger!** Even if it has always been because the idea was that was lost by Excel rounding for the actual value placed in a cell.

So it is our decades old nemesis, for dead sure, and the rounding idea, such as `Werff`'s answer or any of the other rounding approaches is the way to go for dead sure.

Either way though, we can obtain up to 28 significant figures now. Like the above.

This is certain, by the way, not just because I (**claim I did**) above, but because:

1. YOU can too using the approach I used. It shouldn't exist at ALL if it weren't so. And,
2. With the difference out at the 17th significant digit, if it were like it's always been in the past (or at least everyone was dead sure it was), that difference would not exist resulting in the calculated result being different from a typed "27.04"... it would have been cut off at the 15th significant digit and gone forever so OP would never have had this question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.